# How to use several UserTransactions (javax)

Tags: java, transactions

Let's say I have a bean with a method that uses

```
@Inject private UserTransaction utx;
utx.begin();
```

And now I want to test a method that indirectly calls the above. But before, in my test setup, I will call this:

```
@Before public void setUp() throws Exception {
    utx.begin();
}
```

So my testclass and my bean both have an injected javax.transaction.UserTransaction object. Calling the second (bean) utx.begin() will lead to an error: *javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!*

How can I use several UserTransactions, i.e. when I rollback the outer one, I also want to rollback the inner one, even if it has been committed?

Comment: How do you want to rollback something that is already committed?

Comment: but if that is not possible, how am I gonna test my code without changing it too much for tests? I need to rollback any changes made during the testcases